Pre populate values based on other column which is drop down user will select and 3 other columns needs to be autopopulated
I have a small requirement where I need to populate "Check gate for" (column 1) and "Initials of technician" (Column2) based on the selection of value from column Gate.
I tried to create a lookup value column but it fetches the data once the form is saved. Where I want to populate the data when a new form is being created by the user.


Based on your description, I understand that you want to corresponding values filled in the Check gate for column and Initials of technician column when select value in the Gate column.
You could achieve through Power Apps.
1.Go to the list -> Integrate -> Power Apps -> Customize forms.
2.Click the DataCardValue of Check gate for_DataCard on the left Tree view -> Advanced on the right -> Unlock to change properties -> Default -> If(DataCardValue.Selected.Value = "A", "value1", "value2")
Note: In the DataCardValue.Selected.Value, DataCardValue is one of the Gate_DataCard. And please change the properties name of your Power App form in the formula.
3.Initials of technician column as same.
4.Save and publish the form to SharePoint. Then you can see the Check gate for Column filled in with value if the Gate column be choiced.

Thank you so much Emily
